# How to detect if n long messages have encrypted with the same one-time pad?

Tags: one-time-pad

I have a slight idea on what the attack would be. But my question is: how would one detect if n long messages (n>5) have been encrypted with the same one time pad, K?

Comment: Typically, you'd XOR the messages together pair-wise and see if the resulting bit distribution has some detectable patterns (because it should be the XOR of two plain texts).

Comment: With 5 messages you may simply be able to calculate (most of) the key stream. In that case the solution is easy: check if the plaintext is anywhere near the content you expect it contains. If the plaintext of the (additional) messages is fully random (for you) then - of course - you've got no way to check.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, the $K(K-1)/2$ symbolwise difference of the, say $K$, messages should obey the plaintext distribution. If the plaintext is in a natural language, patterns can be detected using various techniques.

If the messages are binary $n=5$ won't be nearly enough. If the messages are in ASCII, $5$ symbols yield 40 bits, so that might be enough, and you'd even rule out key guesses that don't yield printable ASCII characters when XORed with ciphertext.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about 5 (or more) distinct messages, not about messages with 5 symbols each. That said, good answer.

Comment: I thought that too, but also wondered what effect the size of _long_ messages would have. Longer messages should facilitate better statistical analysis of language plain text.